# Text not captured while saving rootview to image

Tags: android, image, scrollview

I'm trying to capture all items in my `ScrollView` and save it as an image.

```
private void takeScreenShot()
{

    ScrollView z = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
    int totalHeight = z.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
    int totalWidth = z.getChildAt(0).getWidth();

    Bitmap b = getBitmapFromView(u,totalHeight,totalWidth);

    //Save bitmap
    String extr = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Folder/";
    String fileName = "report.jpg";
    File myPath = new File(extr, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(myPath);
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), b, "Screen", "screen");
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int totalHeight, int totalWidth) {

    Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(totalWidth,totalHeight , Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
    Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
    if (bgDrawable != null)
        bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
    else
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    view.draw(canvas);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

The resulting image is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBcKg.jpg)

There should be some text in the black area but it isn't showing.

If someone has a solution that may work, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programmatically-take-a-screenshot-in-android

Comment: getBitmapFromView(u,totalHeight,totalWidth); in here u view where?

Comment: View u = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll_view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes it'll set background to black if it isn't set to anything and it'll show up as black text on black background when you create the bitmap.

You can solve this by adding a background color in the .XML file. Be sure to add a background color to the view you want to capture and each item within the views as well. Anything that doesn't have a set background will show up with a black background.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(width , height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

> Just pass ScrollView or it's immediate child view to above function.

Try this, and let me know. Hope it will help !

Comment: it gave the same results